# How to read file line by line and check if each line contains a character in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to read through a text file line by line using bash and pick out specific lines to store then in a vector. The text file I am working with contains names of files which I want to use cURL to download from a server. Each line I am interested in is preceeded by a description line beginning with a # character. I want to read through the file, line by line, check if it contains a #. If said line contains a # then skip it. For those lines which do not contain a # I want to use that information to pass to cURL so I can automatically download the file in question. Thus far I am able to read through it line by line by line with the following code.

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line; do
    echo $line
done <file.txt
```

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ \#*]]
    then 
        echo $line
    fi
done <file.txt
```

I get the following errors.

```
./script.sh: line 4: syntax error in conditional expression
./script.sh: line 5: syntax error near `then'
./script.sh: line 5: `  then '
```

I am using GNU bash 3.2.48(1) for OS X 10.8.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin12)

I have seen this question get asked elsewhere, which is where I came up with my attempt. Though, for some reason it does not work on my machine.

Comment: Friendly reminder that you can run your script through a [linting/analysis tool](http://www.whatswrongwithmyscript.com/) to uncover syntax problems like this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` is good for this for:

```
grep -v "^#" file | xargs -n1 curl
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code is a space before the ]] missing.
And your regex is matching anything. (Zero or more #)

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line; do
    if ! [[ "$line" =~ ^\# ]]
    then 
        echo $line
    fi
done <file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! But, for some reason it is echoing out ONLY those lines that DO start with a #. I want it to echo only those lines which do NOT contain the #

Comment: Just add a `!` between `if` and `[[` and it inverts.